# Emacs 23.3 - default-mode-line-format obsolete?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I switched from emacs 23.1 to emacs 23.3. I had in my configuration file a setting like the  following:

```
(setq default-mode-line-format '(
    string-one
    string-two
    more-strings
))
```

Emacs responds that `default-mode-line-format` became obsolete since emacs 23.2, and says to use `mode-line-format` instead, but simply replacing `default-mode-line-format` with `mode-line-format` does not seem to work. How can I fix it to work with emacs 23.3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `mode-line-format`, you'll notice it says:

```
Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.
```

And what that means is that in order for you to change the value for all buffers, you need to use `setq-default` like so:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format 
      '(string-one
        string-two
        more-strings))
```

Documentation links: [buffer-local variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Value.html), [describe-variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Name-Help.html) (bound to <kbd>C-h v</kbd>).